# Getting path manually entered into a form field

Tags: php, arrays, forms, str-replace

I have a simple form field that allows a user to enter in a specific path to an audio file folder on their computer. They can type in something like:

```
C:\Users\Zebo\Desktop\TwoToneDetect64\audio
```

When the user submits that data, I need to be able to catch all the data being submitted. What happens is the form seems to set it to be a double slash \ when submitted. I tried to do a `str_replace` but the \" is going to obviously make it difficult.

And if I do the following:

```
$temp_dt = explode("\\", $desktop);
```

And then try to rebuild it - I am completely missing for example C: in the `$temp_dt[0]` placement. So I need to figure out how to capture this. It's for the generation of a file that the user would then download and connect to a piece of software, that allows them to use a service.

Comment: Do you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled in your PHP? Turn it off!

Comment: eh - duh! stripslashes will take care of it- thanks!

Comment: @MrTechie check its on first though, if you want to use your code on other setups.

Comment: actually I may have to go that route - because when that path is stored in the database - it removes the slashes from the directory path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have magic quotes on then you should turn it off, if you can. But if you cant then you can fix the quoted super globals by running something like this as your script initialises:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Check for magic quotes, if on fix
 */
function fix_magic_quotes(){
    $inputs = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST, &$_FILES);
    array_walk_recursive($inputs, 'process_mq_array');
}

function process_mq_array(&$value, $key){
    // magic quotes fix
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $key   = stripslashes($key);
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
}
?>
```